# jquery Ajax Content Not loading

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. I am just doing a simple ajax load on some content however the content is not loading all other functions are working but the content does not show. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Its probably something super simple too but.... Here's the code

Main page HTML

```
    <ul><li id="content1">click this</li></ul>
    <div id="ajaxContent"></div>
```

External HTML

```
    <div id="content1"><p>some content here</p></div>
```

...and the JS

```
$(function() {

    var $items = $('ul li');

    $items.bind('click',loadContent);

    function loadContent() {

      var toLoad = 'content.html'+' #'+ $(this).attr('id');

      var $content = $('#ajaxContent');

      $content.append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');  
      $('#load').fadeIn('normal');  

      $content.load(toLoad,'',showNewContent) 

      function showNewContent() {
        $content.fadeIn(1000,hideLoader);
        }

      function hideLoader() {  
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
       }  
   }

}):
```

Comment: Have you looked at the ajax response in firebug ?

Comment: you have a colon instead of a semi in at the very end btw.

Comment: It's not your code, maybe it can't find your content.html. The code works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/BHaEj/15/

Comment: shoot, your right....now what do i do. I guess thats why I couldn't figure out whats wrong. the code is right. any suggestions on why it can find my page

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem. However, i did use `$.post` to work with jsfiddle's ajax api. That might have made a difference. http://jsfiddle.net/k2E7U/1/ Use firebug or the chrome console and see what's going on. Also, quit downvoting people trying to help.

Comment: I get this error in the JS console:

Comment: sorry...XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///F:/tesani/PrintandDesignFactory/butler/working/website/butler-slider/content.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: That's a chrome issue because you're doing ajax on your local server. You can start chrome with `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files` if you want to bypass it.

Comment: haha its just a problem chrome has with file// loading works fine in FF

Comment: Thank you to everybody who had input on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are declaring your functions `showNewContent` and `hideLoader` inside of your `loadContent` function.  That means that you can't reference them until your `loadContent` function has been called (but it needs to use them itself).  Move the functions `showNewContent` and `hideLoader` outside of the `loadContent` function and it should work.

Comment: That's not right. The full scope is parsed befor code is executed. The function can still be called, even if it's declared later. That goes for nested functions too, as demonstrated in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/qaUDY/

Comment: Ah, thanks!  You learn something new everyday.  Are you sure that this behavior is consistent in older browsers as well though?  If he's trying to support IE 7 or 8 will your example still work?

Comment: I only tested it in Chrome. I think it should work in all browsers, but I'm not sure. I don't know the ECMA standards good enough to daresay if it's a rule or not, although I think it should be.

Answer (score 0):

The hash (the part from the `#`) is not sent to the server. If this is the only thing that changes, the browser will not see it as a new url and will not load the page. Change the url to `content.html?id=1` or something, and make sure you handle this GET parameter correctly on the server.

Comment: He is not trying to load a new page, he is trying to load content onto the existing page.  You don't need to change the url.  Also, the hash in this case is to tell the ajax call to load only the element with the specified id.  See 'Loading Page Fragments'. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: You can use the hash to get page fragments.

Comment: @jtfairbanks & Interstellar_Coder. I'm not talking about changing the url. I'm talking about calling a real and *different* url. If you don't do that, the request may not be executed, or the browser may use the same page from the cache. In this case, nothing effectively changes, because you get the same contents you already have. No matter whether it's an AJAX request or a regular request, the hash is usually not sent to the server, although it depends on the browser used.

Comment: Good point.  I assume that content.html is a different page, however (he says it's 'external content').  Still, you are correct in that if it is not a different page then it might not be loaded properly.

Comment: it is a separate HTML file inside my root folder

Comment: If it's in the root folder, where is Main ?

Comment: @Devender Any progress/outcome yet?